# Checking if an application is launchable

Tags: android

I have a list of applications, and I want to weed out all the non launchable/non removeable ones. When I run my program on my phone, it gives me all the ones I dont want also, and yes i have:

```
getInstalledApps(false); /* false = no system packages */
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Are you looking for the same list of activities that can appear on the home screen?

Comment: I don't think that is possible with Activities.  Are you sure you aren't looking for non-launchable _Applications_.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry that was my bad on the question asking, I was tired haha, thanks for editing that, yes launchable Applications, such as the ones that show up in the app drawer